# CORONA SDK: Create a back to main button stopping the already started scenes.

Tags: android, lua, sdk, coronasdk, scene

im developing an APP in corona SDK, it's a serie of tests, so i made every test separately and then i created a main Scene that contains this tests. To handle any click error or misunderstanding i created a "back to intro" button, the problem is, when i start a test (for example test2) i'm in the middle of the test and i use the back to intro button (that takes me to intro, there's no prob with that) the Test2 keeps going and when i try to re-take the test shows an error related to this. I've trying different ways but i can't make it work, here is the code of the button:

```
local function handleButtonEvent( event )

    if ( "ended" == event.phase ) then   
    storyboard.showOverlay( "cerrar sesion", options )
    end
end

local button1 = widget.newButton
{
    width = 60,
    height = 60,
    defaultFile = "images/boton_config.png",
    overFile = "images/boton_config.png",
    label = "",
    onEvent = handleButtonEvent
}

-- Center the button
button1.x = display.contentCenterX+550
button1.y = 35
button1.isVisible=true;

storyboard.gotoScene("test0intro")
```

Plz help :<

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have had this problem. I would advise switching to composer rather than storyboard a lot of these issues are easier to find. I am unsure about storyboard but for composer I know that I had to remove all event listeners, remove the sceneGroup, stop the physics and then remove the scene in the scene:hide method. I'm unsure of what the equivalent of this is in storyboard. Otherwise when I went to restart to the game (as you seem to be doing), the game would crash. Hope that helps!

Comment: I'll try as you say, but unfortunately i'm using storyboard. If i get any god progress i'll post it here.